# set onclick event for image on Pocket IE

Tags: windows-mobile, onclick, pocket-ie

The code works on IE and Firefox but not on Pocket IE on windows mobile. Does anyone have an idea how I can trigger an event when clicking on an image on Pocket IE?

```
<input type="image" src="img/speaker.png" onclick="alert('bla')">
```

I also tried

```
<img src="img/speaker.png" onclick="alert('bla')"/>
```

does not work either.

Comment: What version of Windows Mobile and Pocket IE are you using? The above code appears to work fine on Internet Explorer Mobile 6 in Windows Mobile 6.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with windows embedded handheld, former windows mobile 6.5.3, there are two browser engines on the device: the PocketIE (available before) and the new IE6 engine (started with to be included in some AKU of WM 6.1).

The PocketIE engine's support for Javascript DOM especially events is very limitted, although MS stated a ECMA Javascript 1.1 compatibility. For example, there is NO keyboard event support. See also http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2009/05/14/internet-explorer-mobile-handles-key-events/

The newer IE6 engine is more compatible to windows desktop IE6 and supports, for example, keyboard event handling in javascript.

If you are running at least a windows mobile 6.1 release, you should look for an update to your firmware image, if you don't have IE6 on the device. You can distinguish the engines on start, if PocketIE engine is started, you will not see a mouse arrow cursor apperaing shortly.

If you ca not get an update for your device, you may use alternate browsers like zetaKey.

~josef

Comment: thank you Josef for digging out this old post:) Yes I already got the new os and ie.

Comment: I just scrolled thru unanswered questions before I realized the dates. Sorry